# How to disable sorting in a List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm using a List and sort items.

```
objListOrder.Sort(
delegate(Order p1, Order p2)
{
    return p1.Title.CompareTo(p2.Title);
}
```

I'm having an issue where I need to disable sort and order the items in the order they were added in the list, not in the alphabetical order of corresponding keys.

Is there a way to clear sorting after sort?

Comment: So you don't want to *disable* sorting at all, you want to *override* the default `Sort` behaviour - 2 different things.

Comment: To do that, you need to keep the original list untouched and sort copies instead. There is no "undo"-functionality in a list.

Comment: How do you use `objListOrder`? Where do you keep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to clear sorting after sort?

No, lists do not keep information about the order in which their items were added.

But of course you could add an extra field like `OriginalIndex` to you object and sort the list by this field.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to clear sorting after sort?

No. When you need to use a sorted list use

```
var newList = objListOrder.OrderBy(p=>p.Title).ToList();
```

Which creates a sorted *copy* of the original List

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are after here is for a call to the `Sort` method to have no affect. Given `List<T>` guarantees ordering just have your comparer delegate return `0`, this effectively tells the list that the items should not be shifted

```
delegate(Order p1, Order p2) {
    return 0;
}
```

See [Comparison<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)